# Is it possible to combine a Meta-rig armature with a manually made armature?

Tags: rigging, armature

I made a kind of basic dog armature. As I was wondering how I could make the face armature, I thought of using the face armature from pitchipoy metarig and manipulate it to suit the dog. However, the result didn't come out as I expected. It doesn't seem like they play well with each other. After parenting to mesh, it completely flipped my dog horizonally. So is it not possible to combine two different armatures?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure of any limits, I do believe there is a need to have correct bone names and parenting or chain lengths in place for the rig generation to work properly.

The next [release of blender (2.79)](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79) which is expected to get a beta release soon has some new rigify rigs available with the [updated addon version](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Add-ons). These include basic human and quadruped rigs as well as bird, cat, horse, shark and wolf.

You can download an early [2.79 test build from here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/) that includes the rigify update, I haven't tried it but I expect the updated rigify addon should work with the current release of blender if you want to copy it across to your current install.

Comment: Hmm the bone names I made sure was correct, but as for the chain lengths I didn't know that part. I'm still learning about rigging haha. Oh, that looks really interesting, thanks for letting me know about the new rigs, Yeah I think it will be good to try.